# Triggering "draw linestring" button using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am looking for a way to activate the "draw linestring" button with PyQGIS.

I had a look at this documentation:

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/gui/other/QgisInterface.html

But I can't find the right action:

```
    iface.layerTreeView().setCurrentLayer(layer)

    layer.startEditing()

    iface.name_of_the_draw_linestring_action_here().trigger()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a specific action for "draw linestring" but rather one to add feature, regardless of the geometry:

```
iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
```